# Convert Html scraped data into read and Write CSV file using python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv

Kindly find the following link:

http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/stockreach_financials.aspx?scripcode=505200&expandable=0

I have tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
from pandas import read_csv
import requests

file_path=r'C:\Users\PreciseT3\Desktop\EicherStockDetails.csv'
eicher_stock_url='http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/stockreach_financials.aspx?scripcode=505200&expandable=0'
get_url=requests.get(eicher_stock_url)
target_table=soup(get_url.text,'lxml')
extracted_table_data=target_table.find('table',id='acr')
datasets=[]
col_names=[]
count=1

with open(file_path,'r+') as file:
 writer=csv.writer(file)
 col_names.append('Years')
 for years_row in extracted_table_data.find('tr').find_all('td',class_='TTHeader'):    
    if not(years_row.get_text()=='(in Cr.)'):
        print(years_row.get_text())
        col_names.append(years_row.get_text()) 

 writer.writerow(col_names)

with open(file_path,'r+') as file:
 writer=csv.writer(file)
 for row_headings in extracted_table_data.find('tr').find('td',class_='TTRow_left'):
  col_names.append(row_headings)
  for row_values in extracted_table_data.find('tr').find_all('td',class_='TTRow_right',text=lambda x:'6,188.03' in x or '3,031.22' in x or '1,702.47' in x or '1,049.26' in x or '670.95' in x):
   col_names.append(row_values.get_text())

 writer.writerow(col_names)
```

and my result is as follows:

```
Years,2016,2014,2013,2012,2011,Revenue,"6,188.03","3,031.22","1,702.47","1,049.26",670.95
```

My Requirements are:

- Instead of ((in Cr.)) column name i need to change that as 'year'
- I need to explore it and want to get the data as csv formatted file(write into csv supported file) and also i want to Transpose(T) the rows and columns
- I need to add an extra columns from another html page(Require some examples)

Please kindly help me.I cannot go further. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified this code a bit - but the logic should be straightforward to follow. I've used Cr and Year as the splitter for this fundamental analysis data but you can convert that to millions/qtr as well by adjusting the "main_split" part of the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/stockreach_financials.aspx?scripcode=505200&expandable=0'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

main = []
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    mainSub = []
    for td in tr.findAll('td'):
        mainSub += [td.text]
    main += [mainSub]

splitter = []
for y in range(len(main)):
    splitter += [any('--' in x for x in main[y])]

split_index = [x for x in range(len(splitter)) if splitter[x] == True]

main_split = main[(split_index[7]+2):(split_index[8]-2)]


main_zip = zip(*main_split)
DF = pd.DataFrame(main_zip,columns=[x.replace(' ', '_') for x in main_zip.pop(0)])
print DF
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Really it helped me a lot. Can you please explain the steps   that what have you done so far. and one small change you need to change that is atlast we cannot directly use 'pop' inside zip files.Instead we need to convert them into list then we can convert it.

Comment: excellent work. And also i want to add years in the first column and also i want to add another cloumn which is needed to be extracted from another page(Give me some example using my given link itself).It would be nice,if you explain those steps as much as you can.

Comment: The logic is simple: get all the tables in the webpage in "main", find tables that have '--', find the nth table with '--' that has the required data in main_split, transpose this in main_zip and convert to dataframe. Adding years can be done through similar scrapping - just modifying this code a bit. Merging can be done via pandas dataframe merge. It's interesting that I got into beautiful soup because I started a similar project with NSE a couple of days back :-)

Comment: Thanks but can you assist me that how can i add the years as in this link  [Click here](http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/stockreach_financials.aspx?scripcode=505200&expandable=0#about) to the already given list as transposed. Please explain me and give me some ideas.Thanks in advance

Comment: sir.Please help me. I really need a help how to add years in that list.And i need some explanation (**main_split = main[(split_index[7]+2):(split_index[8]-2)]**) your particular line from your given answer.I am struggling for 5 days.Thanks